# Data type of an address to a pointer to a const char

Tags: c, pointers, types

I have a really simple question:

```
const char *y = "string_test";
x = &y;
```

What type is x ?

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Comment: what type is y?

Comment: I think it's a typo. Instead of 'y', did you mean to write 'q' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you had a typo in your question, and the code is:

```
const char *y = "string_test";
x = &y;
```

x shall be defined as:

```
const char** x; // x is a pointer(Address of) a pointer to a constant char/string
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thank you very much for your help